# how to avoid first lettter capital in textbox html and bootstrap?

Tags: html

i have a form with textboxes and when users is ready to fills some data into the textbox ...textbox field automatically takes first letter as capital

how to disable that...
i want based on user enter enter data in either caps or smalls

**here is my code**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control" list="city" placeholder="Enter city"  required/>
</div>
```

Comment: you can do it using jQuery $('#inputID').val().toLowerCase()

Comment: Not everything in the world can (or should) be solved with jQuery

Comment: i just provided solution it's depends on him either it's usefull or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought your **css** or **javascirpt** set the first letter is captial.

So you can do the following one of the way(**css**)

```css
input.form-control-capital{
text-transform: capitalize;
}

input.form-control{
text-transform: none !important;//You can achive this settings
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control-capital" list="city" placeholder="Enter city(first letter capital)"  required/>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control" list="city" placeholder="Enter city(normal)"  required/>
</div>
```

acheive it.

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform